# Wordpress displaying custom post types and their fields

Tags: custom-fields, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have set up a Custom Post Type called 'RELEASES' - think music cd release.

This post type has fields named 'release_artist', 'release_title', 'release_date', 'release_artwork' and 'release_tracklisting' for entering all of the relevant music cd information.

I am having real trouble actually displaying this information in my Wordpress template.
I have really only had luck outputting a list of the titles and none of the other data.

Any idea what I put in the LOOP to display all of the information? Preferably each in its own LIST item so I can style each separately?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to pull in your fields as needed.  Inside your loop, you can start with the following:

```
<?php 
    $release_artist = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_artist', true); 
    $release_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_title', true); 
?>

<ul>
    <li class="release_artist">
        <?php echo $release_artist; ?>
    </li>
    <li class="release_title">
        <?php echo $release_title; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work. I think it has something to do with the 'ID' aspect. Where does that 'ID' come from? Could you put that above code ina  simple loop for me? I am starting tho think I have it in the wrong place in the loop (or the loop itself is incorrect).

Comment: If you provide me with your current loop, I can take a look and see what could be wrong. If not, I should have some time tomorrow to write up a more in depth example.

Comment: In case my question didn't make sense, I am looking to display the 6 most recent music/cd releases on the home page of my site. So each would contain artist name, album title, picture of album artwork and a link/buy it button. I have not been using my homepage template to put this info into and NOT a custom post type specific template.

Comment: For me `get_post_meta` works as intended. `$into = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'introduction', true); $how_to_reach = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'how_to_reach', true);` and then I can display them as `echo '<p>'.$into.'</p>';  '<p><b>How to reach: </b>'.$how_to_reach.'</p>';`

Answer (score 4):

Are those custom fields? If yes, try [what codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) is saying. Better yet, try [ACF plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

-- edit

If you want to display parts of your pages on other ones (eg. on your home), you need to use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). This is fairly simple function. For your loop, try something like this:

> ```
>       <?php
>         global $wp_query;
>         query_posts(array(
>             'post_type' => 'releases'
>         ));
> ```

```
        while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Opis nazwy'); ?>
            <li <?php post_class(); ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if($key) { echo $key[0]; } else { the_title(); }; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

`$key` is a single value, here set to `release_artists`. It's purely for testing. If it works - feel free to define your own variables.

Comment: yes they are custom fields - I have that part sorted - I just can't display the results on my site.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You should be able to simply `echo` them in theme files. Best way is to create a single page for those particular post types (like `single-releases.php`) and there you can use `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_artist')`.

Comment: This just doesn't work. I can't work out why. Is the 'ID' in your above example dynamically generated? Or are you suggesting I hard code the ID for each one?

Comment: I have read your additional comments from Ryan's answer. If you want to display it on your home page, you have to use `query_posts`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Are you sure these posts are published? Anyway, post your code.

Comment: We are getting somewhere! Thanks again for your help on this. I can now output one of the variables using your above code. As this is delivered via the KEY variable though - how do I list multiple custom field values? Do i need to specify new KEYS? For example...
 
`<?php $key1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_title'); ?>`
`<?php $key2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_date'); ?>`
`<?php $key3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_artwork'); ?>`

Answer (score 3):

From most of the documentation I've seen online, query_posts shouldn't be the go-to function for creating custom queries and loops. The following code snippet might be a good starting point. You should be able to use this inside or outside of the main loop of your themes template files.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'release', //remember this is-case sensitive
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$releaseQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $releaseQuery->have_posts() ) :
while ( $releaseQuery->have_posts() ) :
$releaseQuery->the_post();

// Fetching the post ID for demonstration and for use later
$c_id = get_the_ID();

// After running the_post(), alot of the Wordpress functions (not all) can now be used without supplying the post ID.    
echo get_the_title();
// You could also have used get_the_title($c_id);

// Then:
echo get_post_meta($c_id, 'release_title', true); 
echo get_post_meta($c_id, 'release_artist', true); 

endwhile;
endif;

// Return to the current page's main query
wp_reset_query();

// This should now display the page's title
the_title();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
<?php the_field('field_name') ?>
```

inside your loop. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

About your ID's question:

Every item, like posts and pages in WordPress have an "ID", but they are not normally shown in the lists of them.  There are a number of plugins that will add an "ID" column in your admin.  Search Wordpress.org for "show ids" and pick one you like.  Install it.  Activate it.  You'll see the ids.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=show+id